# Can a streaming collection be implemented in Java?

Tags: java, collections, streaming

I needed to implement a utility server that tracks few custom variables that will be sent from any other server. To track the variables, a key value collection, either JDK defined or custom needs to be used.

Here are few considerations -

- Keeping all the variables in memory of the server all the time is memory intensive.
- This server needs to be a very lightweight server and I do not want heavy database operations.

Is there a pre-defined streaming collection which can serialize the data after a threshold memory and retrieve it on need basis?

I hope I am clear in defining the problem statement.

Please suggest if any other better approach.

Comment: Store the variables in a memory mapped file?

Comment: You could use something like XML or JSON, that's what they're used for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this thing looks very promising, but is in development stage...

[JDBM3](https://github.com/jankotek/JDBM3)

> **Edit** Current version of the file backed collections: [MapDB](http://www.mapdb.org).

Comment: Yep. Looks exactly like what I talked about. Will go through this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

## Database

What you've described sounds exactly like you should use a database (i.e. indexed key/value store, too big for memory but want performance benefits of in-memory caching where possible).

I'd recommend a lightweight embedded database such as [H2](http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html) - it's small, fast and should suit your purposes very well.

Comment: I agree that H2 is good choice, but I think the author doesn't want database

Comment: I know OP said that - I just think he should reconsider. Use the right tool for the job :-)

Comment: if you go with database you need to use some ORM or come up with some custom SQL schema. Using ORM will require more dependency, so sometime you want avoid database to get leaner code.. it's always a trade-off.. .**sigh**

Comment: Use of database would save lot of application side efforts. Tracking the parameters is an additional call already and cannot afford to spend more than few mili second in doing so.

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought of using an on the shelf nosql queue value store? [Redis](http://redis.io/) for example?

If you want it java only you have the option of using a lib like [ehcache](http://ehcache.org/), it would have the functionalities you need.